# how can i print all sequences of given length using only 'O' or 'Z' in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I print all sequences of a given length using only `'O'` or `'Z'` in Python?

For example, if I give `length = 3`

the output would be:

```
'OOO'
'OOZ'
'OZO'
'OZZ'
'ZOO'
'ZZO'
'ZOZ'
'ZZZ'
```

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/  -  SO 
is about fixing _your_ Code - not implementing your ideas. 
Please go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again and if you have questions provide 
your code as [minimal verifyable complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by generating the cartesian product of the elements using `itertools`:

```
import itertools

letters = ["O", "Z"]
length = 3

vals = [''.join(comb) for comb in itertools.product(letters, repeat=length)]

print(vals)
>>>['OOO', 'OOZ', 'OZO', 'OZZ', 'ZOO', 'ZOZ', 'ZZO', 'ZZZ']
```

Comment: python 2, not python 3 as OP tagged his Q. Solid solution.